# Speed of signing with RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, cryptography, hash

I'm currently working on a simple piece of data signing. It's the first time I use signing so maybe I just do somehting wrong. But I don't think its normal that it takes 4.6 seconds to sign 448 bytes using a 512bit RSA and SHA1 hashing.

The code:

```
byte[] Data = enc.GetByte(MsgString); //Get Message as byte[]
//Data is 448 bytes long

RSACryptoServiceProvider Crypter = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
Crypter.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString));

byte[] SignedData = Crypter.SignData(Data, "SHA1"); //Line takes 4.6 seconds
```

Why is this that slow? I found this : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948080 , but thats a problem of .NET 2.0. I'm using 4.0.

Is it normal that this takes that long or is there an error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where do you get `KeyString` from?

Comment: On my virtual machine running a Win XP guest on a Mac OS X host the signature takes no noticeable time. Either `Data` is megabytes in size or `KeyString` represents an enormous RSA key or both.

Comment: KeyString is a string I got out of an RSACryptoProvider before. Its just a 512bit key in Base64 coding. And Data is definetly only bytes. Its just a short string.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know that I have been experiencing that same slowness getting SHA1 signed hashes. The some code that usually signed tens on hundreds of transactions per second, sudently, slowed down to 1 for every 5 seconds.

I was working at home and I was not connected to my company's network. After some googling, I have managed to spot the culprit. A bug the seems to afect RSACryptoServiceProvider on .Net Framework 2.0 - which I believe is EXACTLY the same code used on.Net Framework 4.0.

Since, according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948080, my temporary slowness may be due both RSACryptoServiceProvider's SignData or VerifyData methods trying to communicate to my companys's domain controller, I have decided to establish a VPN connection to my company, which was an imediate success.

Now I get SHA1 hashes again instantly, instead of waiting up to 5 seconds.

I know this is not a solution, but, at least, is a reasonable workaround. It also prevents us from loosing our sanity.

Comment: Had this problem. After reading the same Microsoft KB, we used SignHash instead of SignData. Input for SignHash then just needed to be the SHA1 hash value of the data. Previously:  
`RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); byte[] result = csp.SignData(myData, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());`  
  
Now:  
`RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed(); byte[] shaHash = sha.ComputeHash(myData); byte[] result = csp.SignHash(shaHash, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1) 
I have also found higher throughput by calling SHA1 hash algorithm directly and then passing that has into the SignHash() method instead of SignData() method.  Not sure if it is an implementation issue in the SignData() method but that seems to be my experience.

```
byte[] hash = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(data);
byte[] SignedData = Crypter.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
```

2) If you want to do it all in one method call prevent the need for framework to do a lookup (when you pass the string "SHA1") as it is expensive and may be contributing to the delay Try using the following instead:

```
byte[] SignedData = Crypter.SignData(Data, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
```

Answer (score -2):

Part of the reason why encryption operations take a while to execute is because you don't want people to be able to brute force your algorithm.  What's your use case for signing your data? Does it need to be fast?  Is it a simple check to make sure the data is valid or do you need it to be encrypted?

If you're serious about encryption you might want to check out the bouncy castle stuff:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Comment: Not particular relevant to the question because the answer is no, it should not take nearly that long to sign 448 bytes of data.